# Can my laptop support Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

can this laptop run ubuntu? https://www.pcspecialist.co.uk/notebooks/cosmosXT-15/

these are the specs I choose but I don't knwo if drivers are compatible:

- Intel® Core™ i7 Quad Core Processor 6700HQ (2.6GHz, 3.5GHz Turbo)
- 1TB WD SLIM BLUE 2.5" WD10SPCX, SATA 6 Gb/s, 16MB CACHE (5400 rpm)
- GIGABIT LAN & WIRELESS INTEL® AC-8260 M.2 (867Mbps, 802.11AC) + BLUETOOTH
- 16GB Kingston SODIMM DDR3 1600MHz (2 x 8GB)
- NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 950M - 2.0GB DDR3 - DX12

just to be safe before buy :)

thank you

Comment: YES!! If it can run Windows, it will DEFINITELY run Ubuntu. Ubuntu comes with default drivers preinstalled, just like Windows does. If you wish to update those, you can do it anytime you want. Ubuntu does run on phones and tablets, why wouldn't it run on such high-end laptop?

Comment: @ipselute --- this is an over-optimistic statement. It will run, but how much of the hw (bluetooth, graphic acceleration, etc) will heavily depend on the specific laptop. I had an high-spec laptop, for example, that was impossible to suspend and resume correctly. The best thing is to try with a live USB.

Comment: @Rmano: LiveUSB is definitely a smart thing to do. That suspend issue affects many (me included), but i'd take my chances with Ubuntu any day rather than Windows. Less spyware, no viruses, less junk software and less useless background services running for no user-benefits at all. You can't blame Ubuntu and Windows for missing drivers! It's hardware manufacturers' fault.

Comment: @ipselute I agree mostly with you (this is the reason I run Linux too) but for me a laptop that do not suspend/resume is an useless one --- so I will be more cautious when saying "yes it will work".

Comment: ty all. Any suggestion then? I don't want to buy a laptop if I can't use it :) How can I check?